# Force PositiveInterField in ModelFormSet to not valid if null

Tags: django, django-forms

In models.py:

```
quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

The view is a simple class inherited from ModelFormSetView (Django Extra Views).

Problem : The formset is validated when the enter button is pressed even if there's no quantity entered in each form of the formset. No data are stored in the database (good) but I want a error message to be displayed if no quantities are entered.
Also tried :

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MinLengthValidator
...    
quantite = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MinLengthValidator(1)])
```

without success...
Any help welcomes.

Comment: As a comment when I say the formset is validated = the "success_url" is displayed

Answer (score 0):

You could use `clean_quantity` in your forms. Untested code:

```
def clean_quantity(self):
    quantity = self.cleaned_data["quantity"]
    if not quantity or len(quantity) == 0:
        raise ValidationError(u"Please enter a quantity")
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/.

Comment: Doesn't work. Also tried `def clean_quantity(self): raise ValidationError(u"Please enter a quantity")`. Like it's not evaluated

Comment: Ok, it's a bug in Django and ModelFormSet, like described (https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views/issues/68) and (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24541)